# pyarrow dependency custom build wheel

Tags: c++, pybind11, pyarrow

I am developing a python package using pybind11 which depends on pyarrow to interop between data types in python and C++. Therefore I build apache-arrow with the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

VERSION=6.0.0
VERSIONSTR=${VERSION//./_}
ARROW_DIR=arrow-apache-arrow-${VERSION}
ARROW_TGZ=apache-arrow-${VERSION}.tar.gz
INSTALLATIONFOLDER=/opt/arrow_${VERSIONSTR}
BUILDFOLDER=build_arrow_${VERSION}

if [ ! -f ${ARROW_DIR} ]; then
    if [ ! -f ${ARROW_TGZ} ]; then
        wget https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/refs/tags/${ARROW_TGZ}
    fi
    tar xf ${ARROW_TGZ}
fi
mkdir -p ${BUILDFOLDER}
cd ${BUILDFOLDER}

cmake -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -DARROW_SIMD_LEVEL=AVX512 -DARROW_PYTHON=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALLATIONFOLDER} ../${ARROW_DIR}/cpp
make -j 12
sudo make install

cd ../${ARROW_DIR}/python
PYARROW_CMAKE_OPTIONS="-DARROW_HOME=${INSTALLATIONFOLDER}" python setup.py build_ext --build-type=release --bundle-arrow-cpp bdist_wheel
```

which installs `apache-arrow` and creates the wheel file `pyarrow-6.0.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl`.
With this wheel file installed I can develop my package and all is ok. But how I can deploy a binary wheel for my package?
How can I ensure that the consumer has installed the same `pyarrow` wheel package?
Do I break other packages which depends on the `pypi` version of `pyarrow`? If I want that `mypackage.whl` is compatible with `pypi`'s verison of `pyarrow` do I have to build it with some `manylinux` image?

Comment: I figured out how I can use the artifacts installed with the pypi pyarrow package in cmake. Have a look at https://github.com/maximiliank/cmake_pyarrow/blob/main/cmake/FindPyArrow.cmake